# How can I escape a css file stored in mongodb and load it in the body of the html?

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

Eg:
I have  such a field stored in mongo:

```
"mycss" : "<style id=\"less:ZycusCommonHeader-less-zy-ui\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\">.srchInptBox {\r\n  color='#60b2e2';\r\n}\r\n</style>"
```

Now while fetching this by ajax and appending to the head everything seems to break.

The style tag is not rendering and throws javascript error when it encounters some characters in the value of the "mycss" key.

I use apache commons to escape the css string while storing into mongo from Java.